# How to find number from image in OCR?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr

I'm trying to get the number contours from an image. 
Original image is in number_img:

[image]

After I've used the following code:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(number_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1, 1), 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

img2, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    if (area > 50 and area < 1000):
        [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(number_img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

[image]

Since there are small boxes in between, I tried to limit with height:

```
if (area > 50 and area < 1000) and h > 50:
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(number_img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

[image]

What other ways should I do to get the best contours of number to do OCR?

Thanks.

Comment: Try binarizing the image to get a better quality

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, image has been binarized using threshold

Comment: The result images you show are not binarized (They have a lot of none 0 and 255 colours in them), i.e. if you have done it then altered the image later, it might be worth doing it again

Answer (score 3):

Just tried in Matlab. Hopefully you can adapt the code to OpenCV and tweak some parameters. It is not clear the right most blob is a number or not.

```
img1 = imread('DSYEW.png');
% first we can convert the grayscale image you provided to a binary 
% (logical) image. It is always the best option in image preprocessing.
% Here I used the threshold .28 based on your image. But you may change it
% for a general solution.
img = im2bw(img1,.28);

% Then we can use the Matlab 'regionprops' command to identify the
% individual blobs in binary image. 'regionprops' gives us an output, the
% Area of the each blob.
s = regionprops(imcomplement(img));

% Now as you did, we can filter out the bounding boxes with an area
% threshold. I used 350 originally. But it can be changed for a better 
% output.
s([s.Area] < 350) = [];

% Now we draw each bounding box on the image.
figure; imshow(img);
for k = 1 : length(s)
  bb = s(k).BoundingBox;
  rectangle('Position', [bb(1),bb(2),bb(3),bb(4)],...
  'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2 )
end
```

Output image:

[image]

**Update 1:**

Just changed the area parameter in the above code as follows. Unfortunately I don't have Python OpenCV in my Mac. But, it is all about tweaking the parameters in you code.

```
s([s.Area] < 373) = [];
```

Output image:

[image]

**Update 2:**

Numbers 3 and 4 in the above figure were detected as one digit. If you look at carefully you are see that 3 and 4 are connected with each other, and that is why above code detected it as a single digit. So I used the [`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) function to get rid of that. Next, in your code, even the white holes inside some digits were detected as digits. To eliminate that we can fill the holes using [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) in Matlab.

Updated code:

```
img1 = imread('TCXeuO9.png');
img = im2bw(img1,.28);

img = imcomplement(img);
img = imfill(img,'holes');
img = imcomplement(img);

se = strel('line',2,90);
img = imdilate(img, se);

s = regionprops(imcomplement(img));
s([s.Area] < 330) = [];

figure; imshow(img);
for k = 1 : length(s)
  bb = s(k).BoundingBox;
  rectangle('Position', [bb(1),bb(2),bb(3),bb(4)],...
  'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2 )
end
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the trouble. this is the real image. http://i.imgur.com/TCXeuO9.png I'm still not able to get to your stage from python opencv

Comment: Just updated the answer. Did you try to change the area parameter in your code.

Comment: @Huádéní華得尼 Try explaining the code so that the OP has an idea of what it is actually doing

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, Thank you for good suggestion. Just updated the original code with some comments.

Comment: @moeseth, let us know if you cannot understand the code.

Comment: Hey, thanks. How can my code adjust area filter automatically based on the image?

Comment: @Huádéní華得尼 Any help?

Comment: @Huádéní華得尼, hi, i'm using the following python code. http://pastie.org/pastes/10586539/text?key=4jf9rtwjh2hdwolzxwza. but it doesn't work properly. Can you explain why? http://i.imgur.com/pOpw2nS.png And I just realised your solution got 34 wrong. they are not supposed to be connected.

Comment: @moeseth, I updated code and hope now you can understand it more clearly. If I can try your code in Python OpenCV I will try to add another update. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Huádéní華得尼, I see there are many magic numbers. how can i possibly supply these number dynamically? Please just give me some hints

Comment: As far as I know, it is difficult to dynamically assign parameters for a general solution. What I normally follow is trial and error. You can then select the optimum parameters for your expected accuracy. If you can raise a new question for that you may be able to get some good ideas from others as well.

Comment: @Huádéní華得尼, Hi, actually, i do not need the r at the end. I just need 18 digits. How can I remove the little r? erode it?

Comment: @moeseth, I think now you are going too far from what you asked in the beginning. That is not how SO works. Pls raise a new question for a new issue. Just a simple idea, if you look at the starting coordinates of the bounding boxes of each you can figure out a solution.